Effects of Shaitan
I stop doing haram things and sin and I quit all the bad habits a long time ago and I started to go towards Allah and I can feel that Shaitan is whispering more then ever into my ears and I committed zina will Allah forgive me and accept my dua's and repentance

Yes brother. Allah is the Most Merciful. If you seek His forgiveness, He will keep forgiving you.
